Why command "Reformat code" change use declaration line?
In PhpStorm 2024.1 when running command "Reformat code", the following line of code:
use App\Models\{Department, Doc, Employee, EmployeeSkill, Interviewer, Settings, Skill, User, UserMeeting, UserMeetingInterviewer, UserQuizRequest};

is changed into
use App\Models\{Department,
    Doc,
    Employee,
    EmployeeSkill,
    Interviewer,
    Settings,
    Skill,
    User,
    UserMeeting,
    UserMeetingInterviewer,
    UserQuizRequest
};

I dislike it. Is there a way to leave this line as is (in one line of code)?
